# Can you use random numbers in a CASE statement (SQL Server 2016)

Tags: sql, sql-server, random

I have tried to construct a CASE statement that will fit into a larger SELECT. I want each row to resolve separately (using a different random number per row) but for the random number to be the same when evaluating the case statement within a particular row if that makes sense.

I have tried

```
    SELECT 
    [Player name]
    ,[Stake]
    ,[current jackpot]

         ,CASE

         WHEN 
         rand() < 0.23
         THEN
         'Win'
         WHEN
         rand() BETWEEN 0.23 AND 0.89
         then
         'Lose'
         when
         rand() >= 0.89
         then
         'Jackpot'
         else
         'other'
         end as [outcome]
...
```

but the fact that I sometimes get an 'other' result tells me that each WHEN is creating a different random number to evaluate. I also can't declare a global random number at the start and use that because each line should resolve separately.

Comment: you can declare a variable  and hold this rand() value and use it in your query

Comment: you could seed with something like rownumber, that would make it the same for each row but different for the others. then maybe add `Minute(Now())` to the row so that it is different between runs

Comment: The aforementioned duplicate is not really a duplicate.  The OP in this case is referencing the same random number multiple times in the `SELECT`. This makes a difference.

Comment: select case when rand_value < 0.23 then ..... from (select rand() as rand_value)

Comment: @ventik - unfortunately, T-SQL offers no guarantees over how many times it will evaluate a function/expression vs how many times that function/expression textually appears in the query.

Comment: Case _expression_, not _statement_.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I dont' understand what you mean. You mean that there is a possibility that query "select rand_value as r1, rand_value as r2 from (select rand() as rand_value)" returns row with different r1 and r2 values?

Comment: @ventik - it's certainly *possible*. It's difficult to deliberately provoke this behaviour. I'm just warning that there is very little that T-SQL *guarantees* about the evaluation of expressions.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever as far as I understand different values can occur only if you make calculations with rand_value and only the results of these calculations may differ. Am I right? If you compare pure rand_values thye will be the same

Comment: You should do this in the application layer... or if you insist - create a CLR function for this. Databases are for storing data - not generating random numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can*.  However, `rand()` is evaluated only once per query, not once per row.  Instead, you want to do something with `newid()`.  However, because you reference the value multiple times in the `CASE`, this poses a challenge.  One method is:

```
SELECT . . .
        (CASE WHEN rnd < 0.23 THEN 'Win'
              WHEN rnd < 0.89 THEN 'Lose'
              WHEN rnd >= 0.89 THEN 'Jackpot'
              ELSE 'Other' -- impossible
         END) as [outcome]
FROM (SELECT t.*, rand(convert(varbinary, newid())) as rnd
      FROM t
     ) t
```

Comment: I think you mean "`rand()` is NOT evaluated only once per row", otherwise the original query would work.

Comment: @DStanley . . . I meant "once per query".  Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `RAND()`, a random seed is given since you didn't specify one. Just give `RAND()` a seed and it will remain the same.

```
select 
    case when 1 = 1 then rand(4) end
    ,case when 2=2 then rand(4) end
```

Or use a column value...

```
select 
    case when 1 = 1 then rand(someColumn) end
    ,case when 2=2 then rand(someColumn) end
```

Comment: Won't this mean that every row has the same outcome?

Comment: Yes, if you give it a seed and no, if you use a column which is unique to the row.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is with a **Cross Apply**

**Example**

```
Select [Player name]
      ,[Stake]
      ,[current jackpot]
      ,[OutCome] = case when b.randV<0.23 then 'win'
                        when b.randV between 0.23 and 0.89 then 'lose'
                        when b.randV>=0.89 then 'Jackpot'
                        else 'other' end
 From  YourTable
 Cross Apply (values (rand(cast( NewID() as varbinary )))) B(randV)
```